# How to switch just the domain name but leave the url slug alone

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My company just migrated to WordPress and during the migration we were using a test domain (n.domain.com) to test and develop the new website.

After completion we switched the DNS from “n.domain.com” back to our original domain name of “www.our-updated-site.com.” Both domains are on the same server.

We recently discovered that Google has indexed many of the pages using the “n.domain.com” domain name.

I would like to know how to set up a RewriteRule in the .htaccess that would redirect any “n.domain.com” page to their “www.our-updated-site.com” counterpart?

Example:

> from: *n.domain.com*/item-page/
>
> to: *www.our-updated-site.com*/item-page/

and

> from: *n.domain.com*/company-blog/blog-post-name/
>
> to: *www.our-updated-site.com*/company-blog/blog-post-name/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^n\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.our-updated-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```